# Can't download Xcode from App Store in macOS Mojave in VMware

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, xcode, mac-app-store

I cannot download Xcode from VMware based Mac OS Mojave.
While trying from getting Xcode for High Sierra, I was getting an error that I needed to update the OS. My old MacBook Pro (2010 Mid) didn't support Mojave OS, so, I was to configure Mojave on a VMware. I did it successfully, but when I got to download Xcode (after signing in with my Apple ID). I was not able to download it.
The GET button for Xcode was grayed out.

[image: Xcode GET Button Grey out -> screenshot]

The GET buttons for some other apps work fine.

[image: GET Button is enabled for some other app -> screenshot]

Comment: Xcode 10.2 will run on High Sierra 10.13.6. I've never tested getting Xcode from a VM, but many other App Store/update things won't work for me in VMs, even sitting on top of a regular Mac with Mojave latest.

Comment: I had this issue too - I didn't manage to solve it, I'm afraid, but did want to let you know that you can work around it by download Xcode zip directly from [this link](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue upon completing a vanilla install of a MacOS Mojave 10.14 VM (VMWare). I guess the current Xcode version in the App Store supports Mojave **>=10.14.4**

What solved it for me was to do a software upgrade. After a reboot, I got to version 10.14.5 and the Xcode in the App Store was now available for install.